# "Bags should only be filled 1/2 full" - does the word "only" work as "not more than" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, synonyms, translation

A translator translated the Russian sentence from an instruction

> Пакеты наполняют **не более чем** на 1/2.

as

> Bags should **only** be filled to 1/2 full.

The Russian sentence literally says "Fill the bags to **not more than** 1/2 of their capacity".

Can the English word **only** in the translator's sentence mean "not more than"? Or would the use of **only** mean that the bags should be filled to 1/2 of their capacity, but generally not more and not less?

Comment: The translator's version does indeed mean the bags should end up neither more nor less than half full. "Fill the bags to not more than 1/2 of their capacity" is unambiguous.

Comment: "Bags should be filled to only half-full."

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries show that 'only' can mean **either**:

> **limited to not more than**, *OR* **is not anything other than**, the people, things, **amount**, or activity stated

[Only (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only)

Translators of technical documents, instructions, etc, should make sure they understand the exact intent of the original-language writer. If the instructions are intended to state that e.g. the bags may be a quarter or one third full, but in no case more than half full, then 'not more than' is correct, but 'up to half full' might be better. If the intention is that the bags should be filled **exactly** half full then that should be stated.

Note that in formal writing, we would write 'half' as a word rather than '1/2'.